# How to stop user from login screen second time if app is already started once?

Tags: android

I am making a app having login screen.The validation & other stuff of login is handled by webservice.

My question is that if the user installed the application,then if for the first time user runs the application, a login screen appears to do login through the details given by user at downloading time from market.If user successfully logs in then at second time when he/she runs app,login screen should not appear.

Can anyone help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a successful login you can set a value by using `getSharedPreferences()` to true, and check for that value with a defult of false. 
for example 
on first time the application loads you will `getSharedPreferenced().getBoolean("login",false)`
and if that is false then show the login screen. 
after the first login you could set that value to true `getSharedPreferenced().setBoolean("login",true)`

excuse me if I didn't get the function names exactly right

Comment: Thanks Jason.I think this help in my further process.I am also thinking to do this stuff in same manner,but just want to now if I am right direction or not.

Answer (score 2):

Android has fantastic thing called "SharedPrefrences". These acts as the Registry in Windows. These are used to store user settings. You cannot instantiate this class. Instead use the `getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES_AUTHENTICATION, MODE_PRIVATE);` method to get an instance. Revert back for any query. And Welcome to Stack Overflow. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your welcome to Stack Overflow.Using same piece for coding above stuff.Thanks again.

Comment: I am sorry for that.Now I familiar with the service.Thank U for showing my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know exactly what you are doing, I'd prefer to take a game application for example.If I were you, I'd prefer do it like this.
 I'd place both the log in and game-play screens in one activity. If the user hasn't registered, I'll show the register screen. But if this is already done, I'd show the game-play screen directly. Hope this helps!

Comment: But my registration process should get over when user downloads the app.I think u get clear idea now.